# Convert Byte Array into HTML Image with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, view, arrays

I have a Byte Array field being returned to me by the database, and in the view, I need to somehow output that as an image.  How would I do that in Rails?

Many thanks,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need send this byte by `send_data` helper.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/LogSubscriber.html#method-i-send_data

You need you define another URL who send only this data_byte.

Comment: How would I use this in a view?